# What is a Homeless Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>Based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion),</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Homeless Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Homeless Words™ | Not Homeless Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| MOP | EAT |
| GUM | TAB |
| MONO | DIET |
| ZOOM | QUAD |
| BITE | PUFF |
| PITHY | SKUNK |
| CURRY | HOUSE |
| WETTER | TOMATO |
| PRONOUN | DETUNED |
| COMPUTER | YIELDING |
| MINIMIZE | CASTLING |
| RUTHENIUM | ALGORITHM |
| PROTECTING | ENWRAPMENT |
| TRUMPETING | HELICOPTER |
| OVERPRICING | JUDGEMENTAL |

CSV version:

```
Homeless Words™,Not Homeless Words™
MOP,EAT
GUM,TAB
MONO,DIET
ZOOM,QUAD
BITE,PUFF
PITHY,SKUNK
CURRY,HOUSE
WETTER,TOMATO
PRONOUN,DETUNED
COMPUTER,YIELDING
MINIMIZE,CASTLING
RUTHENIUM,ALGORITHM
PROTECTING,ENWRAPMENT
TRUMPETING,HELICOPTER
OVERPRICING,JUDGEMENTAL
```

Comment: I think these puzzles are more satisfying when there's a meaning connection within the pairs. For example, ignoring the fact that they might not fit the pattern of the puzzle, MOP, BRUSH and DRINK,EAT would be better pairs than MOP, EAT.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Don't you prefer your computer yielding to minimize castling in your ruthenium algorithm? I don't now whether you mop eat, but I like to bite the puff of a pithy skunk at a curry house that has wetter tomatoes.

Comment: A homeless word is obviously a word not in the dictionary

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think a Homeless Word is one

> that uses no letters on the middle row of a typewriter keyboard other than G and H

or in other words

> one that uses none of the letters under your fingers in the standard "home" position of touch typing.

Comment: For a qwerty keyboard ;)